# How can I store the AR.Drone's height in order to control it?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-fuerte, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get the int32 message published in `/ardrone/navdata/altd` in order to control the ARDrone's height. Here is the code I have:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "std_msgs/Int32.h"

using namespace std;

void heightControl(const std_msgs::Int32::ConstPtr& height)
{
  cout << height << endl;
}

from ardrone_autonomy.msg import Navdata

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc,argv,"Height_Control");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("ardrone/navdata/altd", 1, heightControl);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the altitude value is not shown in the terminal screen. However, if I do `rostopic echo /ardrone/navdata/altd` I do get the height shown in the terminal window. Using `rosmsg show ardrone_autonomy/Navdata` I can see that `altd` is type `int32`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67849/how-can-i-store-the-ar.drone%27s-height-in-order-to-control-it?/) by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 182 on 2013-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to do it following these steps:

1. Added to the manifest file the dependency:
    `<depend package="ardrone_autonomy" />`
2. Fixed the code in the following way:

   #include <ros/ros.h>
   #include "std_msgs/Int32.h"
   #include "std_msgs/Float32.h"
   #include "ardrone_autonomy/Navdata.h"

   using namespace std;
   ardrone_autonomy::Navdata msg_in;
   float drone_altd;

   void heightControl(const ardrone_autonomy::Navdata& msg_in)
   {
   drone_altd=msg_in.altd;
   cout << drone_altd << endl;
   }

   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
   ros::init(argc,argv,"Altitude_Control");
   ros::NodeHandle n;
   ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/ardrone/navdata", 1, heightControl);
   ros::spin();
   return 0;
   }

I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) with karma: 182 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2015-04-08**:
ok thanks its fine, but what shall i do when i am not getting any value when subscribing to that topic and looking for **"altd"** i.e., i am just getting as zero.

please help me in this

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2015-04-08**:
Was the drone flying when you looked at **altd**? The AR.Drone won't publish the altd value unless its flying.

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2015-04-08**:
the value of altd is zero even in air and landed and in both i am getting the value as zero
so what should i do now
i had another drone i tried it with too but i ended up with value zero in that drone also...

in case if it publishes when flying, how to access that (i will check whether i did same)

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2015-04-08**:
Odd. It seems like you will need to rebuild your package. I've been using ardrone_autonomy in fuerte, groovy, and hydro with no problems. How did you install it?

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2015-04-09**:
I have installed it in ROS Indigo and it also working well i mean rest of the things.
so what should i do now @Pedro_85 Is there any way to do that??
please help me sir....

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2015-04-09**:
Are you using the coe above to get this measurements or `rostopic echo /ardrone/navdata`? I strongly recommend performing an update to your ardrone_autonomy package with `git pull` and recompiling it.

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2015-04-09**:
I am using rostopic echo /ardrone/navdata to get the altd value @Pedro_85

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2015-04-21**:
It worked for me and i am getting altitude value @Pedro_85
Thank you...

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2015-11-01**:
My navdata subscriber is not calling the calling the callBack function. When i use `rostopic echo /ardrone/navdata` it is showing accurate values but when i write a node, the callBack function is not being called at all. What should i do?

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2015-12-11**:
rostopic echo will not call any function, it only works as display of the topic's traffic

**Comment by [hpurohit](https://answers.ros.org/users/27412/hpurohit/) on 2017-02-28**:
I have similar issue, i can see the value in `rostopic echo /ardrone/navdata` but when i try to subscribe it and print ; it shows nothing.